# how to make input file as nodejs(just like name="hello[]") Compatible with firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

i try make multiple input file button (with same name) and put into firebase storage here is ex.

```
<input  type="title" id="topictitile">
<input  type="title" id="title" name="title[]">
<textarea  type="text" rows= "5" id="content" name="content[]"></textarea>
<input type="file" id="fileButton" name="fileButton[]" /> 
<input type="file" id="fileButton" name="fileButton[]" />  //i have no clue here how to get file and put into database
<button id="add-data" >summit</button>

        <script>
        document.getElementById("add-data").onclick = function(e) {
              var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
              var topictitle = document.getElementById('topictitile').value;
              var topic = document.getElementsByName('title[]');
               var content = document.getElementsByName('content[]');



        for (var i = 0; i <topic.length; i++) {


        var tp=topic[i];
        var ct=content[i];
        var storesRef = rootRef.child('ProcessForQuit/'+category+'/'+topictitle+'/'+i);
                     storesRef.set({
                     topicname: tp.value,
                     detail: ct.value,
                  picturepath : thumbnail //i try to add path with file to database and storage

        });
        }
        alert("Success");
        }
        </script>
```

so database look like this when i click summit 
[image]

but have no clue how to put it at the same time 
sry for my bad english
ps.i'm new in web dev

Comment: Look at this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files so basically you would need to get the file from the file input and then check my link to upload it to firebase storage

Comment: thx a lot :D it's helpful